# Why does the "hand" cursor in macOS have three vertical lines?

Tags: macos, mac, ui

[image: "Hand" cursor in macOS]

What are the three vertical bars in the middle of the cursor supposed to represent?

Comment: Looks like a Micky Mouse glove to me.

Comment: I believe it is a classic white glove which, in real life, had white piping on the back, three stripes of it usually...

Comment: Even the Apple glove has a notch

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking why Apple does or doesn’t do something is out of the scope of what’s considered [on-topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site

Comment: We can quickly remove the 'why' in a case like this, & replace it with a 'what' - what is the hand symbol supposed to represent?

Comment: I think mens leather gloves now usually have the three lines as do white cotton gloves

Comment: @agarza Except that Mickey, like most cartoon characters, only has 4 fingers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a housekeeping, or butler's glove - similar to the ones Mickey Mouse wears.

The 'indentation' actually is on the underside in real life, & is usually a button-fastener, but liberty has been taken to give a more skeuomorphic look.

A tradition since at least Victorian times. A symbol of cleanliness & discreet, professional service.

[image]

More images at Alamy - https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/white-gloves-butler.html